# Can I use postgres json operators on a column of type text having json value stored?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with column as text which is storing a json object as text.Can I use json operator functions to extract value?
For eg

```
create table t1(app_text text);

insert into t1 values('{"userId": "555", "transaction": {"id": "222", "sku": "ABC"}');
```

**WHY DOES BELOW SQL NOT WORK**

```
select app_text -> 'transaction'->>'sku' from t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

to use a json operator, cast text to json:

```
select app_text::json -> 'transaction'->>'sku' from t1;
```